# session being null when redirect to query string url in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm setting `url` with query string when anyone hit such page which is only access after login. I set that controller name as query string and redirect to login page. everything working good till here. but when i login and using `Response.Redirect(returnUrl);` than it is converting my session null. here returnurl is coming as `/Control/Index`. if i simply redirect as return `RedirectToAction("Index", "Control");` than it is working fine.
What can be the problem.

```
Working Good Redirection - RedirectToAction("Index", "Control");
Not Working Redirection - Response.Redirect("/Control/Index");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes down to a question:

> What is the difference between `Response.Redirect()` and `RedirectToAction()`?

Both are used to transfer request from one page to another. Both will give 302 status code. Both can be used for the same purpose, but the devil's in the details.

`Response.Redirect` (as well as `Redirect()` used with just URL) redirects a request to a new URL and specifies the new URL. `RedirectToAction()` terminates execution of the current request and starts execution of a new one using specified action and/or controller name.

`RedirectToAction()` keeps the old request with session. `Response.Redirect()` does not as it's out its scope. `RedirectToAction()` stays on the server to execute another request, while `Response.Redirect()` returns the response and then processes next request from scratch as a separate one.

So, is `RedirectToAction()` better? It's not *better*, it's just meant for different use case. For example, you can't redirect to different website with `RedirectToAction()` as it's out of scope of your local web application. You'd have to use `Response.Redirect()` while passing the URL to the desired webiste.

See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/724972/Difference-Between-Response-Redirect-and-Server-Tr) article explaining the differance in greater detail and illustrating round trips made for both methods. Notice that it does not exactly explain your problem as it shows difference between `Response.Redirect()` and `Server.Transfer()` from ASP.NET Web Pages, but the presented concepts taking place are very similar.

Comment: everything is right. but what should i use now. please suggest me.

Comment: That depends on **where to** you are redirecting. If you are redirecting to a page in scope of your local web application, then use `RedirectToAction()`. In case you are redirecting to an outside website, then use `Response.Redirect()`. There can be more use cases and this is quite a strong simplification.